# problem with updating mysql tables via AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax

i have a 5 stars rating system, on javascript!!! bau  i want to update mysql table, when clicking on stars!!! can somebody tell me how can i update the table!!! 
thanks. . .

Comment: What exactly is it that you don't know how to do ? Making an ajax call ? Or updating a mysql table ? Also, you should tell us what do you use on the server side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Respond to a click by sending an ajax POST to the server. With Prototype, this might look like this:

```
document.observe('click', handleDocClick);

function handleDocClick(event) {
    var star;

    star = event.findElement('.star'); // <= assumes images have the class "star",
                                       // use any CSS here you like
    if (star) {
        event.stop();
        new Ajax.Request('some_url', {
            parameters: {star: star.id},
            onSuccess:  handleSuccess,
            onFailure:  handleFailure
        });
    }
}
```

...and define `handleSuccess` `handleFailure` as you see fit. More on the [unofficial wiki](http://proto-scripty.wikidot.com/prototype:how-to-bulletproof-ajax-requests) and in the [API docs](http://api.prototypejs.org/ajax/ajax/request.html).

You can also use jQuery, YUI, Google Closure, and many many other tools, or use the [XMLHttpRequest](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xmlhttprequest) object itself directly.

That's the client side. On the server side, you'd have to have a page (PHP, JSP, servlet, ASP.Net, FastCGI, old CGI, Perl, Python, ...) that can receive HTTP `POST`s and handle them by updating the underlying MySQL data.